# Margin still there after a margin: 0;

Tags: html, css

I would like your help to understand why my margin is still there?

[image]

As you can see I removed it with a margin: 0; but it is still here and I can't figure out why.
And BTW, how can I remove it?

Thanks, guys!

Comment: Use `display: inline-block` on the `.content` class

Comment: You should post the code in the question instead of linking to an image

Comment: Have you checked that you don't have margin on the element above the one highlighted in your picture?

Comment: @Red is right. You should set it to `display: inline-block;` for `display: block;` prevents other elements to be on the side. Maybe using `display: flex;` works even better for you can set the `width` to, let's say, `70%` and the element that's supposed to be on the right side to `30%`.

Comment: @Red That works well thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no margin. Zero-margin is default for div, you can remove it from your styles.

You need to add `float: left` to `.content`, and `float: right` to `aside` to have them where you want.

```
.content {float: left;}
aside {float: right;}
```

Don't forget to `clear` after floated elements.